# Find a word after and before a string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string like so...

```
ab-0-myCoolApp.theAppAB.in
```

How can I get the word myCoolApp from this string...? Also there are many strings in the same format i.e myCoolApp can be myCoolAppABX or myCoolAppABCD etc.

Comment: maybe using a reg-exp, like `-[^-](*?)\.`...? (I don't know your _actual_ pattern, so I just made this up for the current example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that could be a really brief solution (=one of the many ones) to your problem, but the core concept would be something like that in every case.

---

the input has some random values:

```
let inputs = ["ab-0-myCoolApp.theAppAB.in", "ab-0-myCoolAppABX.theAppAB.in", "ab-0-myCoolAppABXC.theAppAB.in"]
```

and having a regular expression to find matches:

```
let regExp = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "-([^-]*?)\\.", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
```

then *Release the Kraken:*

```
inputs.forEach { string in
    regExp?.matches(in: string, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))).forEach({
        let match = (string as NSString).substring(with: $0.range(at: 1))
        debugPrint(match)
    })
}
```

finally it prints out the following list:

```
"myCoolApp"
"myCoolAppABX"
"myCoolAppABXC"
```

---

***NOTE:*** you may need to implement further failsafes during getting the matches or you can refactor the entire idea at your convenience.

Comment: Shucks, just got late by a min :/ I made the code too very very similar to yours lol :)

Comment: Thanks @holex..:)